# Copilot with Bitbucket

Tags: github-copilot

I'm currently exploring the capabilities of GitHub Copilot and am keen to understand its compatibility with other version control platforms outside of GitHub. Specifically, I'd like to know:

1. Can GitHub Copilot work with private Bitbucket repositories?
2. If so, are there any specific configuration steps required to enable this integration?
3. Are there any security implications to be aware of when using Copilot with private Bitbucket repos?

Any insights or experiences shared would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. Can GitHub Copilot work with private Bitbucket repositories?

No currently Copilot integration is only supported in Github repos. However from what I understand integration with other platforms such as Bitbucket is on the way (I'm actually waiting for that).

2. If so, are there any specific configuration steps required to enable this integration?

No integration other than Github available yet.

3. Are there any security implications to be aware of when using Copilot with private Bitbucket repos?

Yes. This would most likely need to be configured via the Copilot Integration plugin (when/if available) or via your copilot license agreement. We use Copilot in our private code (No repo integration yet though) but our license prohibits Copilot from using our code for training.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it can work with private repositories and you don't need any extra configuration. If you already have it configured in your IDE, it will work.

For more about private repos and how the data is handled, you should check the terms and conditions on GitHub.

Comment: This answer is about Github private repositories, whereas OP asks about Bitbucket.